# OCR an RSA key fob (security token)

Tags: key, rsa, ocr, token

I put together a quick WinForm/embedded IE browser control which logs into our company's bank website each morning and scrapes/exports the desired deposit information (the bank is a smallish regional bank).  Since we have a few dozen "pseudoaccounts" that draw from the same master account, this actually takes 10-15 minutes to retrieve.

Anyway, the only problem is that our business bank account reuires an RSA security token (http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156)--if you are not familiar, it is a small device which shows a random 6 digit number every 15(?) seconds, so I have to prompt for this value before starting.  This is on top of the website's login based security model, so even if you create a read-only account that can't do anything, you still have to put the RSA number in.  We have 5 of these tokens for different people in the company.

From our perspective this is nusiance security.  I was joking about using a web camera to OCR the digits from the key fob so they didn't have to type it in -- mainly so that the scraping/export would be done before anyone arrives in the morning.  Well, they asked if I could really do it.

So now I ask you, how hard (how many hours) do you think it would take to OCR these digits reliably from a JPEG image produced by the camera?  I already know I can get the JPEG easily.  I think you get 3 tries to log in, so it really needs to hit a 99% accuracy rate.  I could work on this on my off time, but they don't want me to put more than a few hours into it, so I want to leverage as much existing code as possible.  This is a 7-segment display (like an alarm clock) so it's not exactly text that an OCR package would be used to seeing.

Also--there is a countdown timer on the side of the display; typically when it is down to 1 bar, you wait until the next number appears and it starts over at 5 bars (like signal strength on your cell phone).  So this would need to be OCRd as well but it is not text.

Anyway the more I think about it as I type this, the less convinced I am that I can truly get this right, so maybe I should just work on it in my spare time?

Comment: Of course it *can* be done, but why bother? Just type the damn digits and save your best work for something useful.

Comment: It's always a great idea to let the entire internet know that a computer in your office automatically logs itself in to your business bank account at a certain hour every day when no one else is around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually easier than it might at first appear. I've used this technique in the past, based on the fact that the digits always look the same, and always appear in the same locations.

Just create ten little masks, one for each of the digits, and prepare a script that splits your one jpg image into pieces, one for each digit. Line up the camera once, then leave it like that. Now you have ten masks for 0-9, and the actual digits on the device. Multiply the pixel values in each mask by each digit, and choose the highest value in each case. That will tell you which mask each digit best fits, and you can use that to determine the digits.

*Disclaimer:* I don't think this is a great idea for security reasons, as other commenters have pointed out.

Comment: I like your answer but I believe this project will stay in the bad idea pile.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by "multiply the pixel values"? If I just multiply the values, I guess the mask of 8 multiplied by any other actual digit will always have the highest value.

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two well-documented open source seven-segment OCR programs designed precisely for the task of automatically reading RSA SecurID fobs:

- ssocr: [Seven Segment Optical Character Recognition](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/).  It has links to other OCR and image processing software.
- LCDOCR.pm: [OCR Build Your Own with Perl modules - May 2007 - Linux Magazine Online](http://perlmeister.com/lme/prod-0706.pdf)

and more general-purpose software that runs on Symbian cell phones may be open by now:

- [Reading LCD/LED Displays with a Camera Cell Phone](http://www.ski.org/Rehab/HShen/Publications/embedded.pdf) - 2nd IEEE Workshop on Embedded Computer Vision (ECVW '06)

The latest work on helping visually-impaired people seems to be [Real-Time Detection and Reading of LED/LCD Displays for Visually Impaired Persons](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3146550/) - Proc IEEE Workshop Appl Comput Vis. 2011

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a software version of the RSA SecurID token. [See here](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1313)

I'm not sure it'll work for your situation (you might have to talk to the bank), but if it does it's probably easier and more reliable than OCR would be.

Comment: Problem with that is: you have to get your admin to register it for you. Good luck, if you come with a story such as "I was considering OCR on the hardware token to do this, but could you ..."

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins you might try feeding a scan of your RSA token into [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) and see how well it performs out-of-the-box.  My guess is that you'll need to do considerable tweaking of the scan contrast/brightness values in order to get a clear text image for scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the OCR API at http://www.webservius.com/corp/docs/wisetrend.pdf - for the volumes you're talking about, it will likely be free for you. To quickly test whether or not the digits will be recognized, you can send a test image to ocr@wisetrend.com and you will get back the OCR results over email.

Comment: It is questionable enough for a business to defeat the bank's 2-factor security system and put access to their own bank credentials on one of their own computers.  Sharing the same information over the Internet with a web service on a daily basis seems like asking for trouble.